# BibDesk plain text preview

Tags: bibdesk

BibDesk usually provides preview formats in TeX, HTML, doc, and RTF. Sometimes, we want to use the complete citation in presentation slides. It would be easier to have previews in plain text.

How do I get citation previews in plain text, which has the same text output as in TeX preview? This is especially useful with copying and pasting citations into presentation slides as line breaks are not included (unlike in TeX preview)

Comment: I don't think you can do this directly, but if you copy as Rich Text and paste it into a plain text editor you'll get plain text. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem.  What are you using for presentations?

Comment: The legen... wait for it... dary Microsoft Office PowerPoint.

Rich Text, however does not output the same thing as TeX preview, in that it simply reformats the fields.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem.  If I select some records in BibDesk and then copy them as Rich Text and paste them into Powerpoint, it formats them as the preview did. What formatting isn't preserved for you?

Comment: Okay. So I right-clicked on a record, then `Copy Rich Text`. When I press `Cmd-V` in PowerPoint, BibDesk crashes, and I get a "Report to Apple" window.

Answer (score 3):

1. Copy the RTF template (`~/Library/Application Support/BibDesk/Templates/rtfExportTemplate.rtf`) into a new file (e.g. `~/textExportTemplate.rtf`)
2. Convert this file to a text file, and change its extension (yuck, what year is this again?) to `.txt`
3. Add the template to BibDesk preferences (**File** > **Preferences** > **Templates**)

You should now be able to Export your bibliography with the **File** > **Export...** menu item. Select your new template in the **File Format** drop-down menu. The bibliography will be exported in the same format as BibDesk default preview, but in plain text.